# Code is not printing stack trace

Tags: java, android

I have the following code in my android application:

```
/**
         * Returns a single customer object based on UUID. */
        public static Customer getCustomer(UUID id)
        {
            try
            {
                Cursor cursor = CustomApp.data.db.query("Customer", customerCols,
                        "CustomerId='" + id.toString() + "'", null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                Customer cust = new Customer(id);

                // Unrelated code here

                if (!cursor.isNull(23))
                    cust.isDeceased = (cursor.getInt(23) > 0); // EXCEPTION

                // More unrelated code here

                return cust;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace(); // This line gets skipped
                return null; // Code jumps to here
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to debug it. Theres an exception on the line `cust.isDeceased = (cursor.getInt(23) > 0);` (*why* I'm getting the exception is another question entirely). When the code reaches that line, it jumps to the `catch` section. I have put a breakpoint on the line `ex.printStackTrace();` but the code skips this line altogether. It just jumps straight to the `return null;` line, and the stack trace is **never** printed. Because of this, it is making it very difficult to debug the code as I am having to guess what is wrong. (If you can see something wrong with that code then please do tell me, but it is not the purpose of this question).

I'm sorry for the lack of information/code I have presented, but as I literally have no idea why this would be happening, I do not know what is relevant and what is not. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Nothing gets printed to the logcat at all during this section of code :(

Comment: `code skips this line altogether` if it is really skipping, your IDE code and your running code are out-of-sync

Comment: Log.e("TAG", "error", ex); try this instead of printStackTrace();

Comment: @rocketboy Would you be able to explain this? Is it a common problem? If it is the problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: Recompile your application and run it again. When the debugger seems to skip lines for no obvious reasons, it is almost always because your running code is the old code and your text file/IDE code on which the debugger is hooked is the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log.e("TAG", "error", ex); try this instead of ex.printStackTrace();
Also try to restart eclipse.

Comment: I will try this, but I don't think it will make a difference, as when the try-catch is triggered, it jumps straight to the return null. The only reason I know this is because I was putting breakpoints everywhere :( I try this now though, thanks :)

Comment: Nope, this didn't work - debugger skips straight to `return null` in the `catch` section. Any other lines are skipped altogether.

Comment: Are you sure you checked LogCat?

Comment: Absolutely positive, I have been using this exact same method when debugging other code. This is the first time I've come across anything like this :/

Comment: Hm, sometimes eclipse stops showing my LogCat altogether. Is your LogCat displaying other stuff? Restarting eclipse might help if it's not.

Comment: "Turn it off and on again" - I didn't think that would actually work, but it did. It's debugging my code properly now. Thank you very much for the suggestion VM. Could you edit your answer to include this? Then I will mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

remove the try catch clause, logcat will show you the detailed exception.